# Predator-Prey type model in Chemistry? Weak acid equilbrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think this is some kind of predator-prey equilibrium problem, correct?
$$A+B <=>C+D$$
$A$ and $B$ react with each other at a certain rate, $k_1$, and create $C$ and $D$, but $C$ and $D$ react with each other at a rate, $k_2$, and create $A$ and $B$.
Simplifying the notation, we can write:
$$L<=>R$$
Thinking like this: The flow starts from the left and goes to the right, and at time $t=0$, $R=0$. What happens during an interval $\Delta t$?
The concentration of $L$ decreases $-\Delta L$ and proportional to the reaction rate $k_1$ (flowing to the right), but is counteracted by the reaction rate from $R$ flowing to the left.
$$-\Delta L = k_1L\cdot\Delta t -k_2R\cdot \Delta t$$
In the beginning, there is no concentration of $R$, but $R$ has to grow. During an interval $\Delta t$, $R$ changes by $\Delta R$, which is proportional to the rate flowing in minus the rate flowing out.
$$\Delta R = k_1L\cdot\Delta t-k_2R\Delta t$$
Then we divide the right and left sides by $\Delta t$, etc.
The quotient between the steady state concentrations is a constant $K_a$:
$$K=\frac{R}{L}\Bigg|_{t\rightarrow \infty}$$
But really, in chem-language concentrations are in square brackets and written as
$$K=\frac{[C][D]}{[A][B]}$$
Is the analysis correct? Analytical solution, Matlab?